# Systemd service file with optional dependency

Tags: systemd, services, dependencies

I am creating a service file for myprog.service, and I want to ensure it starts only after PostgreSQL has started.

However, if the user does not have PostgreSQL installed, then I want it to ignore that requirement and let myprog.service start anyways.

Can SystemD service files have dependencies on an optional (potentially non-existent) service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As described in the [`systemd.unit(5)` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), use a `Wants=` and `After=` directive, as such:

**example.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example service
Wants=postgresql.service
After=postgresql.service
```

`Wants=` indicates that the dependency is optional (as opposed to `Requires` or `Requisite`), and `After=` places it before this unit.